# Python3 f-strings only interpreted in bash

Tags: python, bash, python-3.6, f-string

I am currently learning python and have noticed an issue: If I write a .py file and interpret it with the `python3 myfile.py` command line then the f-string below simply won't show, but if I do the same directly in the python bash it works just fine.

Where could this come from ? (my python version is 3.6.4 (I also have a 2.7 version installed) and I work on macOS)

```
a = "Hello"
b = 22
f"{a} I'm {b} years old"
```

Comment: What does `which python3` tell you?

Comment: What do you mean by "the python bash"?

Comment: Note that if you just put that code in a file and run it, nothing will show because you're not producing any output.  Did you try `print(f"{a} I'm {b} years old")`?

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3

Comment: Okay well it seems I had not understood it that way, I actually didn't think about it, thanks and sorry for the dumb question

Comment: I think what you're calling "Python bash" is actually Python's interactive mode, or REPL (read, evaluate, print loop) -- this has nothing to do with bash, which is a completely different command interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's normal, when executing code in the interactive Python interpreter there is a REPL - *read, evaluate, print* loop.

When executing from a .py file, there is no REPL.  If you want the string to appear on stdout, you will need to actually print it:

```
print(f"{a} I'm {b} years old")
```